# Regex to match format of valid markup language tags

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regex for all type tags either it is html or xml.
I wrote two regex for this

1. `<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>`
2. `<html.*>(.*?)</html>`

these are matching all valid tags,,,but it is matching invalid tags too like:

- `<"font size=12">`

...so I want regex for valid tags only. Can anybody please help??

Comment: i don't understand your question exactly. what do you mean with 'invalid tag'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: XML and HTML aren't regular languages, so you can't match it with a regex. This has been visited many times, as evidenced by a quick google search.

Comment: Invalid tags like <"font size=12">,,,,see this is incorrect format of tag..

Comment: I don't have to write for matching tags.I know we cannot validate html through regex,,,,I have to write regex to match format of tags

Answer (score 1):

Some people worked for this with code coverage to get a good HTML/XML tag matcher (many traps!)

One of the working solution may be: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx/

The Regex is `<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>`

It matchs individually opening + ending tags, useful if you want to remove tags for instance (in fact you can not expect really more with a simple regex as Jithin answered you)

Comment: Can you please explain me sequence of syntax ?How did you write this one

Comment: This regex is not matching <!--[if IE 7 ]>  and this one as well